# Socket: cannot read from BufferedReader and/or write to PrintWriter in certain conditions

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

Good afternoon everybody!

I'm trying to create a simnple messagging application but I cannot find a solution to a big issue. Exactely there are two, big issues.

Here the code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String incoming;
    try {
        while (true) {
            if (!connected)
                break;
            // READING
            if (reader.ready() && (incoming = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                notifier.putCommand(incoming, this);
                incoming = null;
            }

            // WRITING
            synchronized (messagges) {
                for (String message : messagges) {
                    System.out.println("SENDING MESSAGE TO CLIENT: " + message);
                    writer.println(message);
                }
                messagges.clear();
            }
            writer.println("b");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        MyLogger.log(e);
    }
}
```

**Problems:**

1. If I don't every time write junk text to the client `(writer.println("b"))` I cannot read any message on the BufferedReader, sent from it. How is that possible?!
2. On client side I see only lots of "b" but anything sent inside the statement for `(writer.println(message))`. It's really strange, because when I print on the server SENDING MESSAGE TO CLIENT: [...] I see it in the console, but then the message is not sent.

What could it be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about how buffering works, and, in particular, learn to use the `flush()` method to instruct a buffered writer to actually send the data.